# How to Fix Garbled Text in Mobile Version of the Website

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, joomla, joomla2.5, mobile-browser

I just checked my [website](http://localhotchat.com) via my GalaxyS5 smart phone and noticed the some information garbled on bottom portion of site. It normally looks fantastic on the smart phone but this seems like a big problem to me as most of my visitors are mobile visitors.

Attached are screen shots from my mobile device. Can someone identify the issue with the website?

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
    .art-button-wrapper .art-button
{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #FEF200 !important;
  width: auto;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  line-height: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 19px !important;
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 0;
}

.art-button img, .art-button-wrapper img
{
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.art-button-wrapper
{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 31px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.firefox2 .art-button-wrapper
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

input, select, textarea, select
{
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.art-block select 
{
    width:96%;
}

.art-button-wrapper.hover .art-button, .art-button:hover
{
  color: #FFF200 !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.art-button-wrapper.active .art-button
{
  color: #FFF200 !important;
}

.art-button-wrapper .l, .art-button-wrapper .r
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 93px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('../images/button.png');
}

.art-button-wrapper .l
{
  left: 0;
  right: 8px;
}

.art-button-wrapper .r
{
  width: 409px;
  right: 0;
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 401px);
}

.art-button-wrapper.hover .l, .art-button-wrapper.hover .r
{
  top: -31px;
}

.art-button-wrapper.active .l, .art-button-wrapper.active .r
{
  top: -62px;
}

.art-button-wrapper input
{
  float: none !important;
}
/* end Button */











/* begin Box, Block, VMenuBlock */
.art-vmenublock
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.art-vmenublock-body
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
}

.art-vmenublock-cc
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.art-vmenublock
{
  margin: 7px;
}

/* end Box, Block, VMenuBlock */










/* begin Box, Box, VMenuBlockContent */
.art-vmenublockcontent
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.art-vmenublockcontent-body
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}

.art-vmenublockcontent-cc
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.art-vmenublockcontent
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.art-vmenublockcontent-body
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}

.art-vmenublockcontent-cc
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* end Box, Box, VMenuBlockContent */
```

Comment: You're browser's web inspector will guide you with this. Please inspect the element

Comment: @Lodder Who/what is a " browser's web inspector" ? can you please elaborate on that and help me fix this. thanks

Comment: When viewing your website, on your keyboard, press **F12**

Comment: Yes, I am there. What am I supposed to do with this. I have chosen my phone and the screen has shrunk to the size of the phone. what next? @Lodder

Comment: Inspect the element that is causing the issue and look at the styling for it. I suggest you do a little research on how to use the web inspector as it really is a life saver